# Problem with the input layer with Keras: expected dense_1_input to have shape (11,) but got array with shape (15,)

Tags: python, keras

It seems there is a number of [similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=ValueError%3A%20Error%20when%20checking%20input%3A%20expected%20dense_1_input%20to%20have%20shape%20(11%2C)%20but%20got%20array%20with%20shape%20(15%2C)%20site:stackoverflow.com) but I haven't been able to solve my issue.

There is a dataset with 15 features (columns) and one dependent binary feature that I want to predict.

I do all the prep work:

```py
features = df.iloc[:,:-1]
result = df.iloc[:,-1]

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, result, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)
```

Checking the sizes of X_train and y_train:

```py
X_train.shape
```

returns (3392, 15)
And

```py
Y_train.shape
```

returns (3392,)

Y_train is an array: array([0, 1, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0])

Then I build a network:

```py
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

classifier = Sequential()

classifier.add(Dense(units = 8, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim= X_train[0].shape)) # 8 units because (15 features + 1 to forecast) / 2 
# Adding the second hidden layer
classifier.add(Dense(units = 8, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
# Adding the output layer
classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'sigmoid'))
# Compiling the ANN
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
# Fitting the ANN to the Training set
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 10, epochs = 100)
```

And got an error message:
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape (11,) but got array with shape (15,)

I can't understand why it is expecting a shape of 11 (this number isn't used anywhere in my code). In similar questions posted here problems are usually coming from incorrectly specifying a training set's size (like zero instead of whatever the number of features is). But I'm clearly passing the right number to the first layer by writing

```py
input_dim= X_train[0].shape
```

which I can also write as

```py
input_dim= 15
```

with the same result.

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. I also thought the problem was with y_train and did this:

```py
y_train = y_train.reshape(3392,1)
```

but with no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
X_train[0].shape
```

to this

```
X_train.shape[1]
```

to get the number of columns in your matrix.

Comment: It returns 15. 
I've done the following: input_dim= 15 and reran the whole code on a Mac (but it's still in Google Colab). After that everything started to work. However, I'm certain that a particular laptop wasn't an issue